# How To Use Contains On Collection In Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So I am trying to check whether a record from my `engagements` collection contains the matching `value` of the `status` record I am trying to delete.

If the `engagements` contains a matching `value` I want it to return response and not delete the record.

However It seems that it returns that the there is a matching value regardless of if there actually is or not. I have checked the collection to make sure that the `status` being submitted to delete does not exist on the `engagements` collection, so I am not sure what it is that I am doing wrong.

Here is the controller

```
public function destroy(Status $status)
    {
        $statusToDelete = Status::where('id', $status->id)->first();


        $engagements = Engagement::where('workflow_id', $statusToDelete->workflow_id)->get();

        if($engagements->containsStrict('status', $statusToDelete->status)) {
            return response('Status Is In Use', 401);
        };

        $statusToDelete->delete();

        return response('Status Has Been Deleted', 200);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$engagements->contains(function ($engagement) use ($statusToDelete) {
    return $engagement->status->status == $statusToDelete->status;
});
```

Assuming an `Engagement` has a `Status` and `Status` has a property `status`

Comment: thank you for the help however my problem ended up being with my front end code. I was collecting the incorrect `id` to delete so it was actually responding with the correct message because the `status` sent to delete was in use.